# tailwindcss - vertically & horizontalling a div

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I can't seem to find a working way for vertically & horizontally centering a div when using `tailwindcss`.

This is my current code that doesn't particularly works :

```
<div class="absolute flex items-center justify-center">
  <Contact />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a header and you want to ignore the header and center the content the code goes like:

```
<div>
  <div className="flex h-screen flex-col bg-gray-100">
   <header className="text-white text-center fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bg-blue-600">
      Header
   </header>
   <main className="  flex flex-1 justify-center items-center">
      <div className="shadow bg-white rounded-md  w-full text-center">
        Content
      </div>
   </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this [example](https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/center-elements-with-tailwind-css/)
something like `<div class="grid place-items-center h-screen">`

Comment: that sort of works, but I'm looking to have it centred in regards to the entire page if you know what I mean? Like without colliding with the navbar, since in m opinion that looks correct. [image](https://cdn.larkx.xyz/kuq3ceh5.png)

Comment: Your image link is broken, but if you want to center to the whole page vertically, ignoring navbar, you can make the navbar `fixed top-0 left-0 right-0`

Comment: thank you, worked perfectly! 